# Python: Compare two csv files single column and write non-duplicate entries in seperate file

Tags: python, csv, compare

I have two csv files containing email addresses. One file consists of email addresses that i need to remove from the second file. i have a code but it seeems to be giving IndexError.

The sample code i worked on is

```
import csv

# Open details file and get a unique set of links
details_csv = csv.DictReader(open('D:/emails_to_remove.csv','r'))
details = set(i.get('link') for i in details_csv)

# Open master file and only retain the data not in the set
master_csv = csv.DictReader(open('D:/emails-list.csv','r'))
master = [i for i in master_csv if i.get('link') not in details]

# Overwrite master file with the new results
with open('D:/master-output.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, master[0].keys(), lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(master)
```

Content of file 1:

```
abc@123.com
efg@456.com
```

Content of file2:

```
ijk@987.com
abc@123.com
```

Desired Output:

```
efg@456.com
ijk@987.com
```

Comment: which line you are getting error ?

Comment: writer = csv.DictWriter(file, master[0].keys(), lineterminator='\n')

Comment: your list `master` don't have any values it seems, just try to print it

Comment: Yup it's coming as empty. What should i do exactly.

Comment: before accessing list `master` check wether it is having values, you can use `if ..else` or `try ...catch` block. then move forward

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be easily solved with [**`sets`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) like so

```
set1 = {"abc@123.com", "efg@456.com"}
set2 = {"ijk@987.com", "abc@123.com"}

set3 = set1.union(set2) - set1.intersection(set2)
print(set3)
# set(['ijk@987.com', 'efg@456.com'])
```

A good source to learn what can be done with sets is e.g. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/intersection-function-python/.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas dataframe for this purpose.

```
import pandas as pd
details_csv = pd.read_csv('D:/emails_to_remove.csv')
master_csv = pd.read_csv('D:/emails-list.csv')
fn = master_csv[~(master_csv["emails"].isin(details_csv["emails"]))].reset_index(drop = True)
cn = details_csv[~(details_csv["emails"].isin(master_csv["emails"]))].reset_index(drop=True)
final = pd.concat([cn,fn])
df.to_csv(r'Path\File Name.csv')
print(final)
```

sample code is working for your problem but you must add "emails" header to the csv files.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `pandas` package that helps you simplify csv processing. Below is how you use it for your purpose

```
import pandas as pd

details_df = pd.read_csv('D:/emails_to_remove.csv')
master_df = pd.read_csv('D:/emails-list.csv')

# 1. Concat both csv
merged_df = pd.concat([details_df, master_df], ignore_index=True).reset_index(drop=True)

# 2. Drop rows with duplicates email
merged_df.drop_duplicates(subset='emails', keep=False)

# You can save them if you wish
merged_df.to_csv("D:/final.csv")
```

Comment: Hi, i tried this example but it seems to have merged both the contacts rather than removing the duplicates.